Design pattern to auto read attribute values from Redis
My class looks like below
class A_Class:    
    def __init__(self, name:str):
        self.name = name
        self.data = None
        self._load()

    def self._load(self):
        rc = RedisConn()

ac = A_Class("A")
if ac.data:
   # do some data processing
else:
    # do something else   
    # update data
        self.data = rc.read_data(key=self.name)

every time I instantiate A_Class I will see if there is any data for that object in Redis and populate the data field, else data will be empty. This code is difficult to test. e.g. if I don't have Redis for test env. Is there a better way to do this or some suggestions on how to do it differently?
